# Use a for of loop to calculate multiply elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-of-loop

I'm a newbie to JavaScript and I have an exercise about `for...of` but it failed. It returned `NaN`.

Where am I doing wrong and what do I need?

Code:

```js
var arr = [];

function multiply(arr) {
  for (var a of arr) {
    a *= arr[a];
  }
  return a;
}
console.log(multiply([2, 3, 4])); // expect: 24
```

Comment: You need the sum initialised outside the loop and return the sum, not the digit which now suddenly accesses an out of scope item.

Comment: First of all `a of arr` is itself element in `arr`. You do not need to get element like `arr[a]`. This is very cryptic piece of code `a *= arr[a]` stick to fundamentals of pragmatism rather than idiomatic.

Comment: As you are newbie, would recommended you to bookmark this `https://github.com/airbnb/javascript`. 
PS: I am not associated to Airbnb by any means but found that repository good.

Comment: `const product = array => array.reduce((factor, term) => factor * term);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your code modified below. Now working:

```js
var arr = undefined;

function multiply(arr) {
  if (!arr || !arr.length) {     // if the array is undefined or has no elements, return null
      return null;
  }                              // otherwise, continue to do the calculation, it's an array with values
  var result = 1;                // start our result in 1
  for (var a of arr) {
    result *= a;                 // increase the result by multiplying the
                                 // previous value for every value in the array
  }
  return result;                 // finally return
}
console.log(multiply([2, 3, 4])); // expect: 24
console.log(multiply([]));        // expect: null: 0 elements
console.log(multiply(arr));       // expect: null: arr var is undefined
console.log(multiply());          // expect: null: no argument provided
```

Comment: This is a nice explanation, but I feel that -1 isn't quite the right answer for an empty array. Undefined or throwing is probably better.  If you did this with `reduce()` it would throw on an empty array.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yeah. I wasn't sure about what value use for an empty array. I'm going to stick to `null` for now :)

Comment: Thanks, lealceldeiro! When I removed ```var arr = [];``` , It still worked well

Comment: @lealceldeiro . I have a question. When I don't declare ```var arr = []```, my function still know this is an array? Why? Because I call function and transmit elements ```[2, 3, 4]``` -> it understand?

Comment: @HoangDinh yeah, you're right.... look I updated the code, so, now if the value provided is undefined null, or an empty array it returns `null`.